# Why Solaiman bin Dawud(a.s.) is the last prophet who enters the heaven? (Sunni view)

Tags: jannah, prophet-sulayman

I have heard that (according to Shia) it has been narrated from Imam Jafar Sadiq (a.s) that he said:

> Solaiman bin Dawood (a.s.) is the last prophet who enters the heaven
>   (Jannah)

- Initially do Sunni have any hadith regarding this matter?
- Secondly if so, I wonder what the reason is that he will enter the
  Jannah as the last prophet?

(Sunni view)

Comment: There is no attested Hadith saying that Sulaiman (عليه السلام) will be the last to enter the Heaven.

Comment: really? there is no hadith about it(from sunni view). okay, God bless you for paying attention to the question. I wish you write your comment at the place of the answer (of course I you are sure that there is any tradition about the mentioned issue).

Comment: can you clear whether your question is heaven or paradise?

Comment: u indicated a very precise point. uh-huh, I reckon here the actual meaning would be related to Paradise as the main Jannah / hopefully I edit it...

Answer (score 4):

The Hadith - like the one below - that says Prophet Solaiman (عليه السلام) is the last prophet to enter Heaven (الجنة) or that he enters Heaven 40 years after other prophets aren't correct.

> رواه الطبراني في معجميه الكبير والأوسط: حدثنا علي بن سعيد الرازي حدثنا إبراهيم بن هارون بن المغيرة الرازي حدثنا أبي حدثنا عمرو بن أبي قيس عن شعيب بن خالد عن الزهري عن عبد الرحمن بن غنم قال: استعمل عمر بن الخطاب على الشام معاذ بن جبل فكتب إليه أن اعط الناس أعطياتهم واغز بهم، فبينا هو يعطي الناس وذلك في آخر النهار جاء رجل من أهل الرستاق فقال: يا معاذ مر لي بعطائي فإني رجل من أهل الرستاق من مكان كذا وكذا، فلعلي آوي إلى أهلي قبل الليل قال: لا والله لا أعطيك حتى أعطي هؤلاء ـ يعني أهل المدينة ـ سمعت رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم يقول: الأنبياء كلهم يدخلون الجنة قبل سليمان بن داود بأربعين عاما، وإن فقراء المسلمين يدخلون الجنة قبل أغنيائهم بأربعين عاما، وإن صالح العبيد يدخلون الجنة قبل الآخرين بأربعين عاما، وإن أهل المدن يدخلون الجنة قبل أهل الرستاق بأربعين عاما؛ بفضل المدائن والجماعات والجمعات وحلق الذكر، وإذا كان بلاء خصوا به دونهم.
>
> **قال الطبراني: لم يرو هذا الحديث عن الزهري إلا شعيب ولا رواه عن شعيب إلا عمرو ولا رواه عن عمرو إلا هارون، ولا يروى عن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم**

[Reference (Arabic)](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/134422)

The following verses are enough to witness that Prophet Solaiman isn't less rank than other prophets (عليهم السلام).

> وَوَهَبْنَا لِدَاوُودَ سُلَيْمَانَ ۚ نِعْمَ الْعَبْدُ ۖ إِنَّهُ أَوَّابٌ (30) إِذْ عُرِضَ عَلَيْهِ بِالْعَشِيِّ الصَّافِنَاتُ الْجِيَادُ (31) فَقَالَ إِنِّي أَحْبَبْتُ حُبَّ الْخَيْرِ عَن ذِكْرِ رَبِّي حَتَّىٰ تَوَارَتْ بِالْحِجَابِ (32) رُدُّوهَا عَلَيَّ ۖ فَطَفِقَ مَسْحًا بِالسُّوقِ وَالْأَعْنَاقِ (33) وَلَقَدْ فَتَنَّا سُلَيْمَانَ وَأَلْقَيْنَا عَلَىٰ كُرْسِيِّهِ جَسَدًا ثُمَّ أَنَابَ (34) قَالَ رَبِّ اغْفِرْ لِي وَهَبْ لِي مُلْكًا لَّا يَنبَغِي لِأَحَدٍ مِّن بَعْدِي ۖ إِنَّكَ أَنتَ الْوَهَّابُ (35) فَسَخَّرْنَا لَهُ الرِّيحَ تَجْرِي بِأَمْرِهِ رُخَاءً حَيْثُ أَصَابَ (36) وَالشَّيَاطِينَ كُلَّ بَنَّاءٍ وَغَوَّاصٍ (37) وَآخَرِينَ مُقَرَّنِينَ فِي الْأَصْفَادِ (38) هَٰذَا عَطَاؤُنَا فَامْنُنْ أَوْ أَمْسِكْ بِغَيْرِ حِسَابٍ (39) **وَإِنَّ لَهُ عِندَنَا لَزُلْفَىٰ وَحُسْنَ مَآبٍ** (40

[Surat Saad سورة ص](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/translations/english/455.html?a=4010)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the scholars say because he had the most wealth out of all if the prophets and humans and so it has to be reckoned and every detail accounted for; wallahu'alim.

Comment: You would also like to provide some references to support your answer.